# Call to a member function add() on a non-object when trying to add to DateTime

Tags: php, datetime

I had a question on this previously and it was answered and worked, but now I am getting the same error with some different codes and I'm attempting a different outcome.

I am trying to add 1 minute 30 seconds to the current DateTime stamp:

my code is:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); 
date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
echo $date = (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //This echos the correct DateTime in SQL format so I can UPDATE and SELECT easily
echo $datestuff = $date->add(new DateInterval("PT1H"))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //This is where the error is when attempting to add 1 hour
?>
```

question -

How would I add 1.5 minutes to $date and end up with the same format?

Thanks!

Comment: `$date = (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');` -> `var_dump($date);` **VS.** `$date = new DateTime();` -> `var_dump($date);` 1) First step: Do you see the difference (visually)? 2) Second step: *(Know the exact difference and why)*

Comment: you took out the formating piece - no idea why. I don't see any way to add time to it in your comment either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version of your code, which seems to do what you want:

```
<?php

ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); 
date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
$date = new DateTime();
$datestuff = $date->add(new DateInterval("PT1H"))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $datestuff;
```

Important notes:

1. You typically don't want to echo assignment statements. Rather, it's better to assign your variables, then echo their values as needed.
2. Since you are using $date->add, the $date variable should contain a DateTime object. Using "format" converts that object to a string, so you want to do that last.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation as to **WHY** the `format` was causing it to fail. I'll also take the echoing of assignment under advisement. I don't generally do it unless I'm testing something.  Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the line should be:

$datestuff = $date->add(new DateInterval("PT1M30S"))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');